# Gigantic headline in new interface

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, user-interface

I am using [a complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+or+iso-prolog+or+dcg+or+constraint-programming+or+logic-programming+or+yap+or+swi-prolog+or+sicstus-prolog+or+gnu-prolog+or+b-prolog+or+xsb+or+clpfd+or+successor-arithmetics+or+prolog-cut+or+prolog-dif+or+failure-slice+or+prolog-toplevel+or+answer-set-programming+or+theorem-proving+is) to see what I am interested in. The new interface displays this using a very large font. Is it possible to reduce this somehow? I am using Firefox Quantum 60.0.1.

[image]

Comment: I can repro this in Chrome Beta on Linux, and my eyes are not entirely thrilled with this fact.

Comment: I see the same problem. But in fact the whole home page is now full of misaligned or miscentered things, randomly sized titles, heavy weights on things which shouldn't seize the eye... this is a mess. See https://i.imgur.com/svFCRb7.png

Comment: There's absolutely no good reason for this headline to be entirely visible nor to be in a big font. This is the query. We know it, we made it. That's the only thing in fact which isn't an information to us.

Comment: In fact this query is already in the browser's address bar... and I find it to be more readable there, in its reasonably sized font and everything on the same line.

Comment: Mine is so tall, I have to scroll about two pages worth to get to the actual fricken listing. Ouch, this is painful.

Comment: Hmm, AdBlockPlus to the rescue... block element, now the pages are much nicer.

Comment: @false did you know you can "hide left navigation" in your "Settings"' "Preferences"? this at least alleviates the problem somewhat. that left bar is preposterously superfluous (moreso, harmful) anyway.

Comment: @WillNess which would be nice if it would not leave me with no (significant) change at all in the interface spacing, but a huge unused white space to the left.

Comment: @WillNess: No, thx. But now, I do not have a left-navigation on MSO. But I still do have one on SO ...

Comment: @Ben strange, I do get that space back. I use Chrome.

Comment: @false I have "sticky" bar ON, and that whole navigation appears in a *short* menu under the narrow "=" item on the left. No functionality lost.

Comment: @WillNess I use Firefox. Looks like this with the sidebar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzoxG.png. And like this without it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt1y1.png

Comment: @Ben I've just checked it on Firefox, and it's fine there too. Strange.

Comment: @WillNess okay. That's weird now. What version are you using? I run 60.0.2. Website is set to 100% size, no fancy settings enabled, monitor at 1920x1080.

Comment: @Ben I have 60.0.1. but indeed I use zoom greater than 100%. Right now it's on 120%.

Comment: @WillNess at 133% it does indeed look okay, but font is too big for my taste now.

Comment: @false if you prefer it, you can do the same on SO's settings.

Comment: also, there's "Filtered Questions" on your "Network Profile". it looks different, and can be set up to look for the same tags on several SE sites at once: SO, CS, programmers, codereview, etc... :)

Comment: @WillNess: Finally got it! And for the Filters: mnmn. I do have two different queries. One in general, and one specifically for systems (most of which need retagging). Hover my avatar.

Comment: @WillNess: But ... same problem with a giant left margin

Comment: @false I always use at least 120% zoom, so I don't see it. as for Filters, you can define however many you want. But I think I saw that white margin before too, when I happened to set it to 100%. So it just might be a feature of the site, the fixed width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed. [[MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311239/dont-put-the-searched-tags-on-top-of-stackoverflow/311850#311850)]

`/questions/tagged/...` pages with multiple tags will have a header more closely resembling the search results page, with the list of applied tags below the heading element and not inside it.

[image: Screenshot of new heading]

Comment: Nice! <!-- space -->

Comment: It's not as shouty, but it still takes up a lot of space.  The query text is still in the search bar - why not just remove the noise?  We know what we just searched for.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a style definition in `{FIREFOX_PROFILE}/chrome/userContent.css` for hiding that particular heading in Firefox:

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  div#mainbar > div.grid > h1.mb24 {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}
```