# Too much non-whitespace at SO's top

Tags: feature-request, design

The [annoying whitespace at MSO's top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369275/too-much-whitespace-at-msos-top) has been already discussed. In SO, when viewing a tags's questions, that space appears filled with text that is, in most cases, useless.

As an example, I'm a regular participant in the [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag. I don't need such large amount of precious vertical space to tell me what MATLAB is, how questions should be tagged etc. See image below.

Granted, that information could be useful to some people (the few first times they see it, anyway). But for most people, most of the time, it's a waste, and it's annoying.

So:

- Is there an option to remove it, with the current design?
- Failing that, wouldn't it be a better design idea to have that text hidden by default, and show it only after the user clicks somewhere?

---

[image]

Comment: Wait; hasn't that blurb *always* been there? I'm pretty sure it was there in the old layout too.

Comment: I fixed this issue in my userscript [VisualCrumbs](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/tree/com) in the `com` branch.

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple option to remove this: filter on more than a single tag.

You can add an imaginary tag, e.g. [[matlab] OR [unused-tag]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab+or+unused-tag):

[image]

Of course, then you can't use the links on posts, but as a bookmark, it works.

Comment: And then filter on many more tags and you'll re-create the problem [in a different way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369366/gigantic-headline-in-new-interface) :-P