# Style for links on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, design, hyperlinks

I would like to suggest to make links [more visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528665/international-weather-api-for-ruby-on-rails) as links. As it is dark gray hardly stands out compared to the text. I hid a link in this text, can you see it - I mean without me pointing it out now?

It was gray links for me yesterday and up to just before "now" - until I just revisited and now it is a different color. What happened?

Comment: If it is a link that you've *already* visited, it is gray, which is hard to distinguish. If it is a link you've not visited before, it is red. I agree it is a poor design choice.

Comment: To be honest, the red is also dark enough that it's less than ideal in terms of visibility, certainly if you're just skimming through a long post.

Comment: Wow. This feature has actually been implemented - and I think it looks great.

Comment: It *only* took **two months** since it was requested after the [redesign](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update). But at least it's been done.

Answer (score 16):

Well, to answer your edit, the reason that the link changed color for you is because you visited that page. Websites typically have a simple link color, and then a visited link color.

[Link you haven't clicked before](http://erghoeiruhgoiqeurhgoqeirughqoeriguh.invalid/?qeriquwrhtoqiurehtqoieruth)
[Link you have already clicked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281006/style-for-links-on-meta)

Now as far as I know, the change of the link colors isn't terribly hard to do. [This has been posted about before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255983/change-color-of-inline-links-in-so).

I think that an even better option than changing the color is to have them be underlined with dashes. Here are some possible options ([from this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-do-i-write-underline-text-but-with-a-dotted-line)):

[image: link underline options]

Overall, it's a change that really needs to happen. I can't ever actually see where the links are...I have to move my mouse over the post until I find a link somewhere, which is really annoying. I really don't know why it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Internet 101 is that links are always underlined. Except when they aren't...

Comment: +1 for the choice of example links to assure first has already been visited and second hasn't

Comment: @LuisMendo I had originally provided an image. bjb568 edited the post yesterday and added that. I was pretty impressed with it as well :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Well done, @bjb568!