# Camouflaged embedded links fail to be noticeable

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, user-experience

In [How can I ask the NLTK to have synonyms be connected to nearby terms, rather than an island?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525854/how-can-i-ask-the-nltk-to-have-synonyms-be-connected-to-nearby-terms-rather-tha/38540940#38540940), I responded to what another user brought up in a previous comment.

> [image]

I wrote the comment, and even when I look I can *barely* discern that the "example" in "documentation example" is not *identical* in appearance to the surrounding text.

This is bad juju in terms of usability. Even the (foreground) color of my username is much easier to discern, and that in front of a pale *blue* background.

Could we improve the usability of embedded links?

Comment: Yeah, visited links have *extremely* low contrast. It is a problem. Been discussed before.

Comment: [Make visited links a bit more visible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269539/1591669) · [Change color of inline links in SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255983/1591669)